# Relation that is partial order and equivalence?

Tags: relations

Is there any relation on set of natural numbers that is partial order and equivalence? I don't think so because when relation is symetric it can't be also antisymetric. Am I right? Thanks.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation  is a less than general article. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitary_relation is more general.

Comment: $\{(x, y) ∈ N × N | x = y \} so \{(1,1),(2,2),...\}$ is partial order and equivalence? Is $∅$ also partial order and equivalence?